# I need help for a quote form I am creating

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Let me try to explain what I am trying to accomplish.  Let's say that there are forty options available on a quote form.  The customer only wants eight of the options.  I would like to enter a quantity for each of the eight selected items and for the other unselected items to be hidden (and not printed).

I'm sure there is a word for this but I can't think of what it would be.  I am not very technically oriented, so I would appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: I assume you don't know ahead of time which eight the customer wants, so the input form needs to display all 40?  You just want the printed output to be limited to the selected items?

Comment: Exactly.  The form lists all of the options but only prints the items with a quantity.  For example, the User selects Option 1 and enters quantity of 3.  Next, the User selects Option 5 and enters a quantity of 5.  Options 2, 3 and 4 would not print when I print the quote document.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you post sample or snapshot of what the selection form looks like? (row and column structure, how uniform the options are, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I don't know how to pin an Excel file here so you can look at it.  Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Or is there an email address you would feel comfortable sending me?

Comment: I realized that within the context of an answer appropriate to this site, the screen shot wouldn't make much difference.  I'll attach an answer that describes an approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's beyond the scope of an answer to design an application for you, but I can give you an approach and then if you have questions about how to do specific things, you can ask those as additional questions.  There are many ways to do what you want.  I'll describe one that uses just common functions, no macros or Visual Basic, and isn't particularly abstract or convoluted (at least relative to other approaches).

The approach is to create a second sheet that builds what you want to print from the content of the input form.  It is like a template.  This requires that the options on the input form be uniform so that any option can be plugged into any position on the template.

**Input Form**

Make the layout of the options uniform, like a table.  Everything fits into the same descriptive columns and, ideally, each option uses one row.  You can use more than one row but it adds a layer of complexity.  If there is content with vastly different lengths, there are several approaches you can use.

- Put the description detail or other lengthy text in a separate
  reference document with just a brief version as part of the form. 
  That entire reference document can be attached to the printout or you
  can use an approach similar to this one to build a reference document
  containing only the relevant items.
- Use word wrap (this would leave varying gaps between options in the printout since the template would need to accomodate the largest
  entry unless you get fancy).
- Use multiple rows. Since the input form is pre-defined, you could avoid the need to use functions to figure out the number of rows by
  storing the number of rows in a hidden cell for each option. 
  However, dealing with multiple rows makes the solution much more
  complicated.

**Print Template**

You create a second sheet that mirrors the layout of input form.  Figure out the maximum number of options anyone would ever want and add a couple to the count for good measure.  This is the number of template entries you create (you can always add more by just copy/paste).

In a hidden column, you put a lookup function that finds the next printable option.  The first entry looks at all the rows in the input form to find the first one where the quantity is greater than zero and stores that row number.  The second entry looks on the input form from the entry after the previous one to the end and stores the row of the first non-zero option it finds in that range, and so on.  When the print template runs out of non-zero options, you will get an error code or zero, which is fine.

This is done with lookup functions and indirect addresses (i.e., using the content of one cell to lookup something somewhere else).  This allows you to use the same general formula in every one of these cells.  Here are a couple of reference links for lookup and reference functions: [reference 1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/lookup-and-reference-functions-reference-HP010342670.aspx),  [reference 2](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelslookupfunctions/)

Now, every entry in the template has an index to a row on the input form or an error code.  In the content columns, you use a formula that puts a blank or null character if the index is an error code (or zero, depending on what your index formula returns), otherwise the content of the associated cell on the input form for the row given by the index.  Again, this uses the lookup/reference functions and indirect addresses.

Multiple rows can be handled by incorporating additional lookups and calculations for the rows themselves and to compensate for the additional rows.

Build it a step at a time and debug it to get the result you expect, then build the next step using that result.  For example, get the index formula working before you try to incorporate it into the content formulas.  The indirect addressing and lookup functions can get a little convoluted so build them from pieces from the inside out.  Create a simple formula that is part of what you need and verify that it is working.  Then use that in the next "layer" of the formula and so on.